# retrieve a azure variable from a group dynamically using shell scripts task

Tags: shell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a scenario implemented through azure yaml pipeline in such a way.

From shell script I am able to get and print the variable from the azure group named "hello" using
echo $(hello)

Now I dont want to call the "hello" variable directly. I wanted it to call dynamically.

the dynamic value is stored in a output variable before the execution.

```
output = $(git show --name-omly | cut *** 1)
echo $output 
# gives hello as the response

#I tried calling the azure variable like this.

echo $(echo $output)
echo $($output)
```

but both is not printing the azure variable value.

any inputs here are much appreciated.